# In the Great Purge, how many purged military officers served in Tsarist times?

Tags: soviet-union

During the [Great Purge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Purge), a lot of military men were removed (executed, imprisoned, exiled, expelled from the party). I have heard in countless documentaries that those on the list were "perceived as politically unreliable".

So I would like to know, how many of them served as officers in Tsarist times? (Which would make them former Imperials.) That should be an objective criteria investigatable.

I did a brief investigation into the 3 Marshalls who were purged: Tukhachevsky, Blyukher, and Yegorov.

[Tukhachevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Tukhachevsky) indeed served in the Imperial Russian Army, went to two military schools, and made the rank of Second Lieutenant. I don't know if that's an officer or maybe NCO.

[Blyukher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Blyukher) also served the Imperials and made it to the rank of Corporal. I'm not sure if this is considered an officer, but I would think it's at least an NCO.

[Yegorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Yegorov_(soldier)) was also an "army officer", according to Wikipedia, in the Imperial Russian Army until 1905.

So the Marshals, which I believe were the highest ranks in the Red Army at that time, are 3 for 3. Hopefully someone knows of a study into this so some percentage can be had for the whole batch.

Comment: Just a minor remark - it's a bit misleading to refer to the Army of Russian Empire as "White Army" (the latter is a term [solely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_movement) for the Civil War times after 1917). Thus serving in Tsarist Army does not make you a "Former White".

Comment: @seven-phases-max Okay, I edited it to "Imperial".

Comment: Peter the Great's "Table of Ranks" may help.

Comment: OMG... Firstly, the "great cleansing of the Red Army" is 40,000 people who left the Red Army. Among the 40,000, most were dismissed (retired). And only a few were arrested.
Service in the tsarist army is not a criterion for arrest.
Karbyshev is a pond.
Shaposhnikov is a staff captain.

Comment: Simply Тухлый-Rotten (Tukhachevsky) was a cretin. As well as many other "comrades".

Comment: Before the answers start to pile up it would be worth mentioning that counting just in the repressed list does not make any sense w/o counting the non-repressed list (and there you get "virtually everybody" at least as NCOs too).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Indeed, but I was afraid of being too broad. If someone finds a study compiled by some historian, hopefully it will have that count too.

Comment: Service in the tsarist army was not a priority for "Purge".

Answer (score 5):

Russian Wiki features a [list of the repressed highest officers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_(1935%E2%80%941945)) (some of them were prosecuted not in purges but during the war). Unfortunately, the English version does not exist.

While there is a Wiki page for each officer mentioned, the corresponding English pages are rather sketchy. Also unfortunate.

Anyhow, I skimmed their personal information, and it is safe to assume that virtually everybody in that list born before 1897 served in the Imperial Army in a certain capacity during WWI or before, mostly as junior officers or sergeants. There are a few exceptions, most notably [Iona Yakir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iona_Yakir), who was drafted but served as a turner at a military installation.

It is worth mentioning that many non repressed commanders, such as [Shaposhnikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Shaposhnikov) also served at quite high ranks in the Imperial Army.

Comment: Shaposhnikov is a staff captain.
Karbyshev is a lieutenant.
Konev is a junior non-commissioned officer.
Budyonny is a senior non-commissioned officer.
All of them are officers of the Russian tsarist army.

Comment: @Konstantin I have an impression that Shaposhikov was a Colonel.@Konstantin I have an impression that Shaposhikov was a Colonel. Michail Bonch-Bruevich was a General.

Comment: Shaposhnikov became Colonel in September 1917. Though I wonder if such details are worths to be stressed/commented at all (this does not change anything).